# Django UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using the generic Django Views for creating CreateViews and UpdateViews in my views.py - where the field 'Author' is a ForeignKeyField in the model:

```
class BookCreate(CreateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['title', 'author']
```

The generically rendered Creation-Form supplies a DropDown-List where I can choose the Author - so far so good. My question: How can I sort that dropdown alphabetically?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: You can use `order_by` when overriding CreateView's `def get_queryset()`

Comment: What is `author`? A `ForeignKey` to a model you made yourself?

Comment: sorry I am rookie beginner :-) so I put that def inside the class?

Comment: yes, Author is a fk-field in my model

Comment: @Dennis: but to *what* model? What is the *target* model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add some ordering to the model, for example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

This of course means that (nearly) for all components the `Author` will be sorted by name, which is not per see desired behavior.

You can also sort it in the form itself, with:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.order_by('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author')
```

then we can plug in this form with:

```
class BookCreate(CreateView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm
```

Comment: No need to create a form for ordering only. You can get the generated form using `get_form` method and just change the queryset using `fields` attribute.

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan: that is indeed not necessary. But rather *ugly*. Just like overriding `get_context_data` instead of making use of the view that is passed to the template anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering happens in the models section.

So the author model would look something like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    # other fields
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name,')
```

check out the docs for more details :

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#ordering
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to